# Why I got no session exception error from spring jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using springboot and spring jpa as my backend framework. And I got below exceptions when accessing entities from jpa repository.

```
    2016-08-16 20:39:27.528 ERROR 19243 --- [http-nio-8090-exec-8] [.[.[.[.c.c.Go2NurseJerseyConfiguration] : Servlet.service() for servlet [com.cooltoo.config.Go2NurseJerseyConfiguration] in context with path [] threw exception [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
    at com.cooltoo.go2nurse.entities.UserEntity_$$_jvst80d_8.getPassword(UserEntity_$$_jvst80d_8.java) ~[com.cooltoo.go2nurse-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
```

After some searching, I found that this is due to hibernate laze initialize. But what I don't understand is that why my code has such issue. I didn't close the session and all the call is in one http request. Below is my code:

```
@Transactional
private UserBean registerWithChannel(String name, int gender, String strBirthday, String mobile, String password, String smsCode, String channel, String channelid) {
       currentUser = repository.findByMobile(mobile);
        //already existed such user, link with channel user
       UserBean userBean = updatePassword(currentUser.getId(), currentUser.getPassword(), password);
       loginService.login(mobile, password);

} 

@Transactional
public UserBean updatePassword(long userId, String oldPassword, String newPassword) {
        logger.info("modify the password by userId={} oldPwd={} newPwd={}",
                userId, oldPassword, newPassword);

        UserEntity user = repository.getOne(userId);
        if (null==user) {
            throw new BadRequestException(ErrorCode.RECORD_NOT_EXIST);
        }

        boolean changed = false;

        // check password
        if (user.getPassword().equals(oldPassword)) { //the exception happens here

        }
        ...
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with the @Transactional annotation? Or is this because I use the same UserEntity in two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mark the class as @Transactional, then Spring will handle session management rather then method .
@Transactional
public class My Class {
    ...
}
By using @Transactional, many important aspects such as transaction propagation are handled automatically. In this case if another transactional method is called the method will have the option of joining the ongoing transaction avoiding the "no session" exception.

You can also use Propagation

Comment: Does this mean @Transactional over methods will bread hibernate session?

Comment: no it not break transaction, but hibernate also confuse about what to do with transaction like use existing transaction or start new transaction.so you have to specify with propagation Like : REQUIRED,REQUIRES_NEW,MANDATORY ETC